# How can I disable cache for particular section or block

Tags: magento-1, blocks, cache, ce-1.6.2.0

I have developed a top bar cart functionality for store front that displays latest three products added to the cart this works great when cache is disabled but when i enable the cache it showing weird subtotal in top cart and weird products in cart.

This make me sad :'(

I know this is happening because of cache. Is there anything that I can disable the cache for this section only? I have tried disabling the block html cache and check now this was working great but I found the category flat is having unspecified issues when block HTML is disabled.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How? Please share the details with us. Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try

```
    <reference name="needed block">
        <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
    </reference>
```

or

```
    <reference name="needed block">
        <action method="setCacheLifetime" />
    </reference>
```

to set it to null.

But probably it is better to use ajax.

There is a good article about `null` or `0` meaning <del>http://blog.kyp.fr/make-a-clean-sweep-of-commons-magento-cache_lifetime-workarounds-usage-in-cache-block-policy/</del> <sup>*(link is broken)*</sup>

Comment: hmm use of ajax could solve the problem. I will try this thanks for your help.

Comment: I thought `null` = never cache and `0` = cache permanently?

Comment: `null` = never cache, right. However, I'm not sure it is possible to argument value to `null` with `<action>` directive.

Comment: `<action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>` worked for me. TNX!

Comment: Setting the Cache Lifetime to "0" does not disable the cache. Only "null" will disable it!

Comment: I tried with editing this answer to a correction, but it was not possible, so I can only downvote it for "you can try" - answer or not. But you can try sounds harsh for a Q&A site. Especially as others have commented that the answer is wrong in part - and it would have been easy to correct it.

Comment: So the correct method is? <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action> and none of the other solutions?

Answer (score 11):

You can disable cache in getChildHtml(). This is what the signature looks like:

```
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
```

This should do the trick:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('block', false);
```

Comment: i have tried this.. actually is have coded in top.phtml
this is not working in that case

Comment: That might be cached as well so I guess it wouldn't have much effect. Is there a chance you can pull it outside of that part? I don't think there are any other options...

Answer (score 9):

In the particular xml file.
Say catalog.xml

In that for particular reference block
In that block set the action of cache limit to null

Example of catalog.xml

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.product.cat.related" as="related_cat" template="catalog/navigation/list_cat.phtml" after="-" >
        <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
        <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```