# Layered navigation state not updating, state block not rendered

Tags: cache, blocks, layered-navigation

When I click on a filter, page reloads and **filters products correctly**, but new state does not appear on sidebar menu. For some reason **state block is not rendered**.

I tried with **default theme** and it **works**, so it should be theme specific. Weird is that this anomaly **does not happen on localhost**. Even more weird is that when I turn on **template hints** with [Magento debug module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug-8676.html), it refreshes something and *state block* suddenly gets rendered. This however does not happen when I manually activate *template hints*.

So activating filters and removing them works but state block does not update. Only thing that makes state block render updated information is toggling template hints from Debug Module. What could cause that?

I just in case mention, that I also tried to deleting both, `state.phtml` and `view.phtml` in my custom theme `catalog/layer`, but this did not change anything.

What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you verify that it's really not rendered and checked the sourcecode your browser is getting? I had some strange things, that the block was rendered, but not displayed in the browser. Either it was some CSS stuff or invalid HTML structure.

If you're sure it's not in the source your server is delivering: Did you try to turn off the cache? Maybe it's a cache issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, state block did not get rendered. I checked source and also rendered blocks with Magento Debug module, but YOU WERE RIGHT, it was cache issue. +1 for that :) Disabling `Blocks HTML output` cache made state block appear as it should. Now though I have next question. How should I deal with it? Eventually I would need block cache enabled, can I disable it only for stat block somehow? I think I should update my question with new info.

Comment: What dependencies does your block have? Did you add them in the cache id? There are already a lot of question on this platform about cache issues, maybe you can find something in there.

Comment: I did `<reference name="left">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.leftnav</name></action>
        </reference>` and `<reference name="my_custom_block">
            <action method="insert"><child>catalog.leftnav</child></action>
        </reference>` inside `<catalog_category_layered>` handle. I know nothing about adding stuff to cache id. How should I do it? Should I make new question about it or update this one?

Comment: Best make a new question :)

Comment: Found solution from here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/how-can-i-disable-cache-for-particular-section-or-block