# Is there a way to make frequent changes to a Magento site without sacrificing caching/indexing performance?

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, cache, full-page-cache, server-setup

Running Magento Enterprise 1.14.

My client makes very frequent changes to the content of their store. Things like new products, changing product details, prices, inventory, stock, images, etc. etc. Naturally, this means that the Magento cache and/or indexes have to frequently be refreshed.

This, in turn, has a knock-on effect on performance, because if the cache is being purged ten times a day, there's zero chance for any meaningful amount of cached data or cached full pages to accumulate.

Customers unlucky enough to view a page at the exact moment of a heavy reindex might also see some "funny" looking pages.

Is there a setup which would allow me to maintain a steady level of caching and indexing while still allowing users to make frequent changes?

*Some notes:*

- I'm aware performance should not rely on the cache. That's not what this question is about.
- I do use a FPC pre-warmer/crawler but to little effect.
- I've considered deploying a staging server where changes could be made and then fully cached, then simply doing a bulk insert/update between the two Magento databases - stupid or potentially workable?

Comment: Magneto 1.14 has partial indexing built in, and if you're using the FPC properly then the invalidation of the cached items would rebuilt. Both should not require full reindexing  or cache purging.

Comment: async reindex and fpc should work as normal, you can even invalidate zend opcache per file. dont see any issues here

Comment: @B00MER Can you elaborate on what you mean by using it properly, please? We just edit category products/prices/etc. then reindex but sometimes changes are not shown until cache is manually flushed.

Comment: @MagenX The problem is the frequency of the edits. The cache is constantly being invalidated. Even if one category is changed then performance will suffer because non-cached pages are slow to load/re-generate.

Comment: @WackGet Since my comment was getting to be too long, just made it into an answer.  Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install [Aoe_Templatehints](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints) and [Aoe_Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler) and take a look at your blocks caching status of the areas that are frequently edited to make sure proper block cache keys are being used, as the FPC should notice the changes differ and invalidate its cache for rebuilding without intervention.

The new indexer in 1.13+ of EE has partial indexing which means there shouldn't be a need to do full re-indexes.

Some Related Questions/Answers:

- [When are the indexes invalidated?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89579/when-are-the-indexes-invalidated/90121#90121)
- [Magento FPC - What makes this stay up to date?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/magento-fpc-what-makes-this-stay-up-to-date/89328#89328)