# How to turn off cache for a block?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, cache, block-cache

i want to completely remove from cache the header-minicart. 
It is confused when magento cache and fpc work together.

how can i do that?

Comment: remove it from Blocks HTML output cache

Comment: @Adrian, my mistake i have deleted my comment

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/how-can-i-disable-cache-for-particular-section-or-block,  this list all possible ways to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a particular block cache by using below code,

```
<reference name="needed block">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>
</reference>
```

or

```
<reference name="needed block">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime" />
</reference>
```

OR from backend:

> goto -> admin -> dashboard -> System configuration -> cache
>   management -> disable for block.

find find the attached screen shot:

[image]

Comment: i have done from admin, but why to be off for all? the changes is in local.xml? to another file?

Comment: you can do it in local.xml